# How can I edit this specific .eps file into a transparent image on photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal, eps

I'm kinda new with Photoshop so please bear with me.

I found this [.eps file on freepik](http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/efecto-de-luz-con-forma-circular_1015004.htm#term=magiccircle&page=1&position=15) that I want to use for personal use.

I opened the .eps file on Illustrator and everything looked fine there, then I tried removing the background and only moving the effect part to photoshop, but without any background the image turns to this:

[image: A Weird Black Appears]

I noticed that if I simply add a grey background on photoshop and make the circle have a screen blending that it looks similar enough to what it should, but as soon as I remove the background, it goes back to having that black thing around it.

I need this to end up being a transparent image to use elsewhere, I could simply look for something else similar, but I kind of want to learn how to make this work, there must be a way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in photoshop simply as follows:

1. Select the black color with **Select → Color Range...** w

   - Enable invert option
   - Full fuzzyness
     OR
   - Use the black option
   - Full fuzzyness

   OR

   Copy the red channel, by control clicking the red channel in the channels palette.
2. Duplicate the layer (<kbd>ctrl+J</kbd>) the new layer now has only the non-black are but is still decontaminated by color or use  **Select → Select and Mask...**
3. Then apply **Layer → Matting → Remove black matte** or in select and mask crank decontaminate

Depending on what result you want, tweak to your hearts content

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop lacks a colour to alpha filter which would be ideal for such an edit. Although there used to be a plugin for it, I'm not sure if it's still around but if I remember correctly it only worked on 32bit versions of the software. The most recent version of Photoshop is only 64bit, so I don't think it will work. I suppose you could do a search for it if you have an older 32bit version of PS installed.

Anyhoo, the easiest way by far to fix this is to export the image you currently have (as a PNG obviously).

Open it in the free software GIMP, click Colors > Color to Alpha, choose black as the colour, hit OK. Then export as PNG.

Here's one I made using GIMP's Color to Alpha filter

[image]

Comment: Photoshop has this same functionality its called **Select  > Color Range**, and then click on the layer and then **Layer > Layer Mask > Hide Selection** combined with possible refine selection or remove black matte. Being a 2 step process allows you to do more edits... But harder to find.

Comment: Although your solution works well enough, it messes with the colours in a way that GIMP's colour to alpha filter does not - especially with decontaminate enabled in refine selection, and the remove black matte doesn't make much difference either. [see this screen capture](https://imgur.com/a/tOojL) for the comparisons between the GIMP and PS solutions. So, although quite similar, the functionality is not really quite the same as GIMP's. But thanks for sharing!

Comment: If you actually copy the black layer from channels instead of using the color selection then you get the exact same thing as you did.